# how to filter e filter string from list in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

this is the list which i have filtered from a nested json using the below json_query

Please see the content of  tmpdata

```
{
  "content_length": "4883",
  "status": 200,
  "cookies": {},
  "changed": false,
  "strict_transport_security": "max-age=15768000",
  "x_api_total_time": "0.234s",
  "_ansible_item_result": true,
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "json": {
    "job_tags": "",
    "type": "job",
    "scm_revision": "",
    "status": "successful",
    "credential": null,
    "force_handlers": false,
    "job_slice_number": 0,
    "ask_credential_on_launch": false,
    "started": "2021-02-24T06:48:29.884643Z",
    "ask_job_type_on_launch": false,
    "start_at_task": "",
    "event_processing_finished": true,
    "elapsed": 27.82,
    "finished": "2021-02-24T06:48:57.704791Z",
    "ask_variables_on_launch": true,
    "ask_limit_on_launch": false,
    "job_slice_count": 1,
    "ask_skip_tags_on_launch": false,
    "extra_vars": "{\"domain\": \"abc-cn-1\", \"mgmt_password\": \"admin123\", \"mgmt_server\": \"192.168.20.30\", \"fingerprint\": \"9125544D272B5AD28F3E9AB7BC8AA3F276E45064\", \"fwcmd\": \"fw sam -v  -J src 192.68.10.10\", \"targets\": [\"abc-cn-c1\"]}",
    "use_fact_cache": false,
    "name": "test-Checkpoint",
    "created": "2021-02-24T06:48:29.003796Z",
    "url": "/api/v2/jobs/1198/",
    "vault_credential": null,
    "verbosity": 4,
    "job_args": "[\"ansible-playbook\", \"-u\", \"root\", \"-vvvv\", \"-i\", \"/tmp/awx_1198_e4iie_fm/tmpz4bfietf\", \"-e\", \"@/tmp/awx_1198_e4iie_fm/env/extravars\", \"chkpoint.yml\"]",
    "modified": "2021-02-24T06:48:29.720325Z",
    "unified_job_template": 7,
    "project": 6,
    "limit": "",
    "timeout": 0,
    "host_status_counts": {
      "ok": 1
    },
    "result_traceback": "",
    "launch_type": "manual"
  },
  "server": "nginx/1.12.2",
  "connection": "close",
  "_ansible_parsed": true,
  "allow": "GET, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS",
  "redirected": false,
  "cookies_string": "",
  "_ansible_ignore_errors": null
}
```

i am using the below json_query to filter the output from the tempdata

```
   - name: "search for traget fw"
     set_fact:
       job_status2: "{{ tmpdata | json_query('[json.status, json.extra_vars]') }}"
```

please see the output from the above facts, you can see dict inside the list and i want to filter only expected output mentioned below

current output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "successful",
        "{\"domain\": \"abc-cn-1\", \"mgmt_password\": \"admxxxxxin123\", \"mgmt_server\": \"192.168.10.20\", \"fingerprint\": \"9125544D272B5AD28F3E9AB7BC8AA3F276E45064\", \"fwcmd\": \"fw sam -v  -J src 192.68.10.10\", \"targets\": [\"abc-cn-c1\"]}"
    ]
}
```

expected output:

```
["successful", targets": ["abc-cn-c1"]]
```

please help me id if this is possible

Comment: Please do consider making an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since there is no way someone can provide you with actionable advice without knowing the shape of `tmpdata`. That said, it could be just a matter of `...[json.status, json.extra_vars.targets]` have you tried that?

Comment: @mdaniel sorry i have updated the input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two answers to your question if you want to continue to use `json_query`, and one that sidesteps that mess entirely. We'll start with the latter because it's less typing for me :-)

```yaml
- set_fact:
   job_status2: '{{ [ tmpdata.json.status, (tmpdata.json.extra_vars|from_json).targets] }}'
```

the second is a slight variation on that, in that *someone* needs to resolve that embedded JSON to a dict and (AFAIK) JMESPath has no such ability

```yaml
- set_fact:
    job_status2: "{{ newdata | json_query('[json.status, json.extra_vars.targets]') }}"
  vars:
    newdata: >-
     {{ tmpdata
     | combine({"json":{"extra_vars", tmpdata.json.extra_vars|from_json}}, recursive=True)
     }}
```

I mention that one mostly for the case where you are doing other things with `json_query` and thus it would be advantageous to know how to coerce the structure to be friendlier for JMESPath

and finally, you can cheat and use [the JMESPath literal notation](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#id15) to embed the already JSON-ified string right into the query

```yaml
- set_fact:
    job_status2: "{{ newdata | json_query('[json.status, `' + newdata.json.extra_vars + '`.targets]') }}"
```